# Loop through each row from filtered data

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to run a simple script which will loop over each row where certain conditions are met (i.e. column 8 is 0). The filtering works, in that I can see the filter being applied correctly, but the code always uses an unfiltered version of the data, and so always loops over ALL rows in the sheet.

```
// Get sheet
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<sheetId>").getSheetByName("Log");

// Filter out all items that have already been revoked. (this works)
var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(["1"]).build();
var pendingRevocations = sheet.getRange("A:J").createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(8, filterCriteria);

// Loop through each to remove these permissions
for each (var pendingRevocation in pendingRevocations){

  // This doesn't work. I've tried various ways, and in all of them
  // I either get ALL rows (unfiltered) or just an odd selection of 
  // blank rows

  // Do stuff with pendingRevocation
  var name = pendingRevocation[9];
  Logger.log("Name:" + name);

}
```

I'm sure this must be simple to achieve, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to loop through a filter object, not rows of the spreadsheet.

Comment: is the filter always gonna be set through scripts?

Answer (score 3):

The filter hides rows on the sheet but can't be used to filter out rows in the script.

Try this instead, using `getDataRange()` method [1] to get all the data and loop through it while applying an if condition to filter:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][7] == 0) {
      // Do stuff
    }
  }
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange

Comment: I use this method regularly. _Great approach!_

Answer (score 0):

If the filter isn't from the script there's also the .isRowHiddenByFilter() [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition) (there's an error in their doc tho, it's just a copy/paste of previous method...)

Could also be useful since the "to remove permission" comment might mean you wanna do more than log stuff?

You could do :

```
  var range = sheet.getRange("A:J");
  var nRows = range.getLastRow();

  for (var j = 0; j < nRows; j++) {
    var row = j+1
    if (sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(row) != true) {
      //do stuff like :
      var name = sheet.getRange(row, 8).getValue()
      Logger.log("Name:" + name)
      //and
      var toChange = sheet.getRange(row, <column index>);
      var oldVal = toChange.getValue()
      var newVal = 0;
      toChange.setValue(newVal)
      Logger.log(oldVal +" changed to :" + newVal)
      continue
    }
  }
```